# Django ViewSet, get data from model without foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views

My Models

```
def ModelA(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50)
    val_a = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=100)
    val_b = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=100)
    modelB = models.ForeignKey(modelB, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_constraint=False)

def ModelB(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50)
    val_c = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=100)
    val_d = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=100)

def ModelC(PostgresModel):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=50)
    val_e = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=100)
    modelB = models.OneToOneField(ModelB, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)
```

My ViewSet

```
class ModelAViewSet(ListDataResponseMixin, APIKeyViewSet):
    endpoint_permissions = [APILicenseKeyPermission.Codes.A]

    queryset = ModelA.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ModelASerializer
    filterset_class = ModelAFilter
    filter_backends = [DjangoFilterBackend]
```

My Serializer

```
class ModelASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        fields = (
            "id",
            "val_a",
            "val_b"
        )
```

When querying `ModelA` I would like to get `val_e` from `ModelC`.  I am learning django, and previously when I needed to do something like this, I would use `select_related`, however, since there is no clear path from ModelA -> ModelC using foreign keys, I am not sure how to proceed. (My base models cannot change).  How would I modify my ViewSet to include the needed `ModelC` data in my `queryset`? And then for my `ModelASerializer` I would like to just be able to add in `val_e`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use a CharField, like this:

```
class ModelASerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    val_e = serializers.CharField(source='modelB.modelc.val_e')
    class Meta:
        model = ModelA
        fields = (
            "id",
            "val_a",
            "val_b",
            "val_e"
        )
```

This is possible because ModelA has a ForeignKey to ModelB and ModelB has One To One relation to ModelC. More information on [source](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) can be found in documentation.

Comment: `ModelB` does not have a foreign key to `ModelC` only `ModelC` has a foreign key to `ModelB`.  When I try the above, I get `Original exception text was: 'ModelB' object has no attribute 'ModelC'.` 

(note: I cannot add a foreign key from B->C)

Comment: I see there is a OneToOne reference from ModelC to ModelB. OneToOne relation works both ways: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/

Comment: In there example, they are able to query `p1.restaurant`.  

When I try that `val_e = serializers.CharField(source='modelB.val_e')`

I get `Original exception text was: 'ModelB' object has no attribute 'val_e'.`

When I try  `val_e = serializers.CharField(source='modelB.ModelC.val_e')`

I get `Original exception text was: 'ModelB' object has no attribute 'ModelC'.`

I have read both those links several times, however, I am not able to make this work.

Comment: Would it make a difference that `ModelC` is a `PostgresModel` instead of a `models.Model`) ?

Comment: As this is a reverse relation, you need to lowercase the attribute name, like ModelC becomes modelc (like the answer mentioned). Also I have no idea what is PostgresModel. If you mean you are using Postgres database, then the code shared here should work.

Comment: It is from `psqlextras` it is how the model is defined, but that probably shouldn't matter.

Even lowercasing, it is same issue: `Original exception text was: 'ModelB' object has no attribute 'modelc'`

Comment: So it can find `ModelB` but still no modelc relation (yes a relation exists in the DB)

Comment: What happens if you change the field: `modelB = models.OneToOneField(ModelB, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False, related_name='modelc')`?

Comment: As per the documentation, the solution provided here should work, unless its deviated from original code you have. hence I suggest if you have an actual code with actual library information, please put it here, because otherwise, based on your hypothetical code, its difficult to identify what is wrong. Also, please put the actual stacktrace in the question if possible.

Comment: Adding `related_name='modelc'` was the issue, once I added that ,everything worked.  Thanks for all your help!  I would have never figured that out